# OpenTBS / PHP - How can I create a multipage document(docx) in OpenTBS?

Tags: php, opentbs

**Scenario**

I am trying to create more than one page in OpenTBS (.docx file) from a PHP array with each array element corresponding to a page of data.

**Question**

*How can I insert new pages for every data element?*

Any help would be appreciated.

**PHP Code**

```
    foreach($actionItems as $actionItem)
    {
                array_push($data, array(
                    'ActionItemID' => $actionItemID,
                    'ActionItemTitle' => $actionItemTitle,
                    'Assignor' => $assignorLastFirst,
                    'Criticality' => $criticality,
                    'Owner' => $ownerLastFirst,
                    'AltOwner' => $altOwnerLastFirst,
                    'AssignedDate' => $assignedDate,
                    'DueDate' => $originalDueDate,
                    'ECD' => $ecd,
                    'ClosureDate' => $closureDate,
                    'Team' => $team,
                    'Department' => $department,
                    'Source' => $source,
                    'Project_Phase' =>$projectPhase,
                    'ActionItemStatement' => $actionItemStatement,
                    'ClosureCriteria' => $closureCriteria,
                    'Notes' => $notes,
                    'ClosureStatement' => $closureStatement
                ));


        }

        $TBS->MergeBlock('a', $data);
```

**Template Screenshot**

[image: Page Template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is explained in the DOCX template of the [OpenTBS demo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo) provided in the OpenTBS package :

1. Make sure that the first paragraph of the page has the property giving a *page break before*.
2. Use a block defined with the alias `tbs:page`. This alias is given by OpenTBS and it helps to found the bounds of the page (or pages) according to the page-break defined in the paragraph properties

Example: `[a.ActionItemID;block=tbs:page]`

Comment: Thank you!  I moved the first block out of my table (the [a.ActionItemID;block=tbs:page]) and I put <w:pageBreakBefore /> before the block I moved (that is, right before [a.ActionItemID;block=tbs:page]) and I was able to generate all pages successfully.